# Find minimum set of rays intersecting all voxels

Tags: math, geometry, raytracing, voxel

Okay first I wasn't sure if this was better suited to the MathSO so apologies if it needs migrating.

I have a 3D grid of points (representing the centers of voxels) with pitch varying in each dimension, but regular. For example resolution may be 100 by 50 by 40 for a cube shaped object.

Giving me `nVox = 200,000`.

For each voxel - I would like to cast (nVox - 1) rays, ending at the center, and originating from each of the other voxels.

Now there is obviously a lot of overlap here but I am having trouble finding how to calculate the minimum set of rays required. This sounds like a problem that has an elegant solution, I am however struggling to find it.

As a start, it is obvious that you only need to compute

```
[nVox * (nVox - 1)] / 2
```

of the rays, as the other half will simply be in the opposite directions. It is also easy in the 2D case to combine all of those parallel to one of the grid axes (and the two diagonals).

So how do I find the minimum set of rays I need, to pass from all voxel centers, to all others?

If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great. Any and all help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem really isn't about three dimensions in any specific way. All the conceptual complexity is present in the two dimensional case.

Instead of connecting points individually, think about the set of lines that pass through at least two points on your grid. Thus instead of thinking about points initially, think about directions. For 2-D these directions are slopes of lines. These slopes have to be rational numbers, since they intersect points on an integer lattice. Since you have a finite lattice, the numerator and the denominator of the slope can be bounded by the size of the figure. So your underlying problem is enumerating possible slopes for rational numbers of bounded "height" (math jargon).

There's an algorithm for that. It's the one used to generate the [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) of reduced fractions. If your figure is N pixels wide, there will (in general) be a slope with denominator N in the somewhere, but there can't be a slope in reduced form with denominator >N; it wouldn't fit.

It's easier to deal with slopes between 0 and 1 directly. You get the other directions by two operations: negating the slope and by interchanging axes. For three dimensions, you need two slopes to define a direction.

Given an arbitrary direction (no necessarily a rational one as above), there's a perpendicular linear space of dimension k-1; for 3-D that's a plane. Projecting a 3-D parallelpiped onto this plane yields a hexagon in general; two vertices project onto the interior, six project to the vertices of the hexagon.

For a given discrete direction, there's a minimal bounding box on the integer lattice such that two opposite vertices lie along that direction. As long as that bounding box fits within your original grid, each of the interior points of the projection each correspond to a line that intersects your grid in at least two points.

In summary, enumerate directions, then for each direction enumerate where that direction intersects your grid in at least two points.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, it'll take me a while to check this approach as it's outside my expertise but your help is much appreciated and I'll get back to you with the results. Cheers!